# detecting class names un-used on html code

Tags: javascript, css

exist any way or tool to detecting class names un-used on html code.

i have some html code with old bootstrap; jquery and personalised css style like this:

```
<div class="clear fot-her likes tab-sub">content</div>
```

but i need purge un-used if `fot-her` class name not apply any style get add it to a list and show in and alert.

i find only this but i can get the class name:

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element [, pseudoElt]);
```

and this only get the element by class name given:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names);
```

script

```
function checkClassCSS() {
    let doc = document.all;
    let style = document.styleSheets;
    var listofClases = []
    Object.entries(doc).forEach(([key, element]) => {
        let classes = element.className.split(/\s+/);
        let new_classes = []
        classes.forEach((cl) => {
            if (cl != '') {
                new_classes = new_classes.concat(['.' + cl]);
            }
        });
        listofClases = listofClases.concat(new_classes);
    });
    listofClases = listofClases.filter(v => v != '');
    listofClases = Array.from(new Set(listofClases));
    var SelectorClass = []
    Object.entries(style).forEach(([key, node]) => {
        let rule = node.cssRules;
        Object.entries(rule).forEach(([key, cssSelector]) => {
            SelectorClass = SelectorClass.concat([cssSelector.selectorText]);
        });
    });
    SelectorClass = SelectorClass.filter(v => v != '');
    SelectorClass = Array.from(new Set(SelectorClass));
    var missing = [];
    listofClases.filter(function(x) {
        if (!SelectorClass.includes(x)) {
            missing.push(x);
        }
    })
    console.log(missing);
}
```

I can't get the unused class names correctly for example: `col-lg-4` may be used in html code but it still appears in `missing` variable.

Comment: So you want to cycle through your CSS and check if the class names exist? Is the CSS an external file or inline?

Comment: A bit unclear; you looking for a way to check if a class does not apply any styles? And you want those classes to show up in a list once found? Is it something for developing/debugging on something you want to implement? A bit more context would be helpful

Comment: @ColinG if you see the example given, i have html code, with class atribute and with style class name... i whan to detect if every one of this like `fot-her` name is applying any style to the element. if its notthing applying style, show an alert with the class name; example: `fot-her` seek for style applying instead of, search `fot-her` on css in-line or css external file.

Comment: @EmreKoc it's something I'm looking for; and with the existing documentation in javascript I have not managed to program it.

Comment: Well, your code to get the CSS is going to get all the CSS _rules_ that are being used; not just classes. So you'll actually have to pull the class names out of the rules. I would just use a regex to match them: /\.[\w\d\-_]+/g then query document.getElementsByClassName to see if anyone is actually using them.
Additionally, you're not going to be able to access rules for cross-domain CSS files due to the XSS restriction.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Get `document.all` and look for `tagName=="STYLE"`.
In all of those (if any), look for `sheet.cssRules` and for each, `selectorText`.
These are supposed to be the classes - collect the into an array.
Then, go through all the other `document.all`, look for `classList`.
Compare them to array - if found in array, good, if not: alert.
Good luck!

Comment: any one have remove all comment i have update the question; i have create the script but not work correctly with media query i dont know what i am missing.

Comment: Great job!  I'll take a look soon.
I thought you deleted your second comment, so I deleted the reply to it.  
It seems you were right about rats - one of them down-voted this answer instead of saying why...  Perhaps they deleted the comments too!

Comment: Went over your edited code - worked for me!
Seems like you are doing a little bit of extra work...  
My I suggest: Instead of adding `.` to class names, remove `.`,`#` and any other prefixes when you collect class names.

Comment: So?  Is it working?  If not - what isn't working?  I've tried and it worked for me (Windows, Chrome).

Comment: i dont know around negative votes... but in some cases the script not work for media querys